# How to solve Exception thrown; "Too many connections" error - Error is thrown at con3.Open();

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I have an exception thrown at con3.Open(); whenever I start the application . I have an Exception thrown; "Too many connections" what do i need to do please.

```
private void cmbartname_out_bulk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str_display = @"select * from bulk_available where article_name='" + cmbartname_out_bulk.Text + "'";
    using (var con3 = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=1001;persistsecurityinfo=True;Max Pool Size=3600;database=theshopdb;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd_str_display = new MySqlCommand(str_display, con3))
        {
            con3.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader_cmb = cmd_str_display.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    while (reader_cmb.Read())
                    {
                        string pdt_code = reader_cmb.GetString("article_code");
                        int pdt_qty = reader_cmb.GetInt32("quantity");
                        decimal pdt_unit_price = reader_cmb.GetDecimal("unit_price");
                        string pdt_measure = reader_cmb.GetString("article_measure_unit");
                        decimal pdt_total_value = reader_cmb.GetDecimal("total_price");

                        // Using the variables here
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ert)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ert.Message, "Exception caught", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            con3.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimum"

Comment: Don't you think you have an SQL injection issue as well?

Comment: In addition to the other two comments, change the event handler from selectedindexchanged because it is quite likely that while the read operation is on, the selectedindex is changed by the user triggering another connection before con3,close() is executed.